# Invisible html element on "view page source"

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup, htmlelements

I am trying to read an html page in my java code using Jsoup library. This is the link to the page: http://www.alkhaleej.ae/

The part in the page that I am interested in is the horizontal menu bar at the top of the page (which has the news categories). When I right click on that menu bar and choose inspect element, the html elements of interest are visible to me under the tag `<div id="MainMenuCenter">`. However, when I run my code, it turns out this tag is actually empty, and all the children of this tag get invisible. I also tried to view the complete document using "view page source" on the webpage. I surprisingly found this element empty (no children) as below.

```
<div id="MainMenuCenter">

</div>
```

Therefore, I am not able to access the information I need in my code. What is really going on? Did the developers hide the children of this element on purpose? Can you suggest a way to make the children visible to my code? Thank you.

Comment: the  list seems to be loaded via ajax and formatted via jquery.

Comment: I agree. It seems to be loaded after the page is loaded. So, can Jsoup retrieve the data of this element in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the data by looking at the network traffic on

**Inspect element -> Network**

Check the traffic one by one or use the find tools. 
If you find the match data, you can re-obtain it by visiting the url who serve the data..

Maybe like: `http://example.com/serve.php?category=car&page=1`

Comment: I hope if you can elaborate. I have checked the network section but the URLs there looks nothing like the link you provided. Also, how am I supposed to figure out which one is the one I am looking for? Finally, would it give a URL that has the div subelements I am looking for or what kind of data the URL would have?

Comment: Have you check at the url's response in the developer tools?

Comment: The other way to do is by checking if the javascript contain any words for `MainMenuCenter`